# How is my question about the Windows Registry off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, reopen-request, off-topic

I've got the question

> https://superuser.com/questions/1651185/does-windows-have-any-protection-against-programs-that-refuse-to-uninstall (deleted automatically by Community, only for 10K+ users)

... that was marked as "off topic". I can't understand why.

- The [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) says nothing about the Windows Registry being off-topic.
- The tour says I should ask about:

  - Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking *(yes, this is an issue with computer software)*
  - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered *(yes, this is a real problem!)*
- They  also say to not ask about:

  - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
  - Questions with too many possible answers or require an extremely long answer
  - Videogames, consoles, or other electronic devices, unless they connect to your computer
  - Websites or web services like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
  - Shopping, buying or product recommendations
  - Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
- None of these describe my question.

So why is it off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question."

Is the close banner on the question. Its *incredibly* broad and talks about a strange, hypothetical situation.

> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

Seems hypothetical, unless you can name and shame some software boneheaded enough to actively tell you it can't uninstall, as opposed to a half dozen other sneakier things.